Telegram 2 Discord forwarding bot problem
I'm making a bot which must forward a message from a certain Telegram channel to the channel on the Discord server. I made bots in both services, got channel IDs.
There's problem: when I send a message in TG channel, bot ignores it and does not send it in DC channel.
The bot code (where's real token values and channel ID values are replaced by dummies):
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, filters
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# Telegram Bot token
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = 'tgtoken'
# Discord Bot token
DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN = 'dctoken'

# Telegram Channel ID (from)
TELEGRAM_CHANNEL_ID = 'tgchannel'
# Discord Channel ID (to)
DISCORD_CHANNEL_ID = 'dcchannel'

# Creating bots
telegram_bot = telegram.Bot(token=TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)
discord_bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

# Message handler
def telegram_message_handler(update, context):
    message = update.message
    chat_id = message.chat_id
    if str(chat_id) == TELEGRAM_CHANNEL_ID:
        text = message.text
        photo = message.photo[-1].file_id if message.photo else None
        send_to_discord(text, photo)

# Message sender (to Discord)
def send_to_discord(text, photo):
    channel = discord_bot.get_channel(int(DISCORD_CHANNEL_ID))
    if photo:
        photo_url = telegram_bot.get_file(photo).file_path
        embed = discord.Embed(description=text)
        embed.set_image(url=photo_url)
        channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        channel.send(text)

# Updaters and logging in
def main():
    updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.text | filters.photo, telegram_message_handler))
    updater.start_polling()

    @discord_bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'We have logged in as {discord_bot.user}')


discord_bot.run(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


I disabled Privacy mode for my TG bot via BotFather, made this bot as Admin in the group the channel is attached to. So TG says "has access to messages".
From the side of Discord bot, I set all intents on, checked the bot's role in the server to write in the channel (Announcements type).
I thought that maybe to replace the channel ID (channel is public and has the readable ID (which is used in the link)) by the group ID (which group, read above). No effect

There's a log of the bot program when executed (executed under my Linux based laptop (Ubuntu 22.04.1, Python 3.10.6-1~22.04)):
2024-04-18 10:57:00 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2024-04-18 10:57:03 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: ...).

When the program is executed, Discord shows the corresponding bot is online despite the absense of the string "We have logged in as (botname)" (according to the code).
